# magento/inventory-composer-metapackage = 1.1.3 magento 2.4.3

Tags: msi

where of composer.json should i add this line? i had tried in different ways but no luck to get inventoy- (MSI)

```
`{ 
    "name": "magento/magento2ce",
    "description": "Magento 2 (Open Source)",
    "type": "project",
    "license": [
        "OSL-3.0",
        "AFL-3.0"
    ],
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true,
        "allow-plugins": {
            "laminas/laminas-dependency-plugin": true,
            "magento/magento-composer-installer": true,
            "dealerdirect/phpcodesniffer-composer-installer": true
        }
    },
    "version": "2.4.3",
    "require": {
        "php": "~7.3.0||~7.4.0",
        "ext-bcmath": "*",
        "ext-ctype": "*",
        "ext-curl": "*",
        "ext-dom": "*",
        "ext-gd": "*",
        "ext-hash": "*",
        "ext-iconv": "*",
        "ext-intl": "*",
        "ext-mbstring": "*",
        "ext-openssl": "*",
        "ext-pdo_mysql": "*",
        "ext-simplexml": "*",
        "ext-soap": "*",
        "ext-xsl": "*",
        "ext-zip": "*",
        "lib-libxml": "*",
        "colinmollenhour/cache-backend-file": "~1.4.1",
        "colinmollenhour/cache-backend-redis": "1.11.0",
        "colinmollenhour/credis": "1.11.1",
        "colinmollenhour/php-redis-session-abstract": "~1.4.0",
        "composer/composer": "^1.9 || ^2.0",
        "elasticsearch/elasticsearch": "~7.11.0",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^6.3.3",
        "laminas/laminas-captcha": "^2.10",
        "laminas/laminas-code": "^3.5.1",
        "laminas/laminas-crypt": "^3.4.0",
        "laminas/laminas-db": "^2.12.0",
        "laminas/laminas-dependency-plugin": "^2.1.0",
        "laminas/laminas-di": "^3.2.0",
        "laminas/laminas-eventmanager": "^3.0.0",
        "laminas/laminas-escaper": "2.7.0",
        "laminas/laminas-feed": "^2.13.0",
        "laminas/laminas-filter": "^2.11",
        "laminas/laminas-http": "^2.6.0",
        "laminas/laminas-i18n": "^2.7.3",
        "laminas/laminas-json": "^3.2.0",
        "laminas/laminas-mail": "^2.9.0",
        "laminas/laminas-mime": "^2.8.0",
        "laminas/laminas-modulemanager": "^2.7",
        "laminas/laminas-mvc": "^3.2.0",
        "laminas/laminas-server": "^2.6.1",
        "laminas/laminas-servicemanager": "^3.6.0",
        "laminas/laminas-session": "^2.10",
        "laminas/laminas-soap": "^2.9.0",
        "laminas/laminas-stdlib": "^3.2.1",
        "laminas/laminas-text": "^2.6.0",
        "laminas/laminas-uri": "^2.5.1",
        "laminas/laminas-validator": "^2.6.0",
        "laminas/laminas-view": "~2.12.0",
        "league/flysystem": "^2.0",
        "league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3": "^2.0",
        "magento/composer": "1.6.0",
        "magento/magento-composer-installer": ">=0.1.11",
        "magento/zendframework1": "~1.14.2",
        "monolog/monolog": "^1.17",
        "paragonie/sodium_compat": "^1.6",
        "pelago/emogrifier": "^5.0.0",
        "php-amqplib/php-amqplib": "~2.10.0",
        "phpseclib/mcrypt_compat": "1.0.8",
        "phpseclib/phpseclib": "2.0.*",
        "ramsey/uuid": "~4.1.0",
        "symfony/console": "~4.4.0",
        "symfony/event-dispatcher": "~4.4.0",
        "symfony/process": "~4.4.0",
        "tedivm/jshrink": "~1.4.0",
        "tubalmartin/cssmin": "4.1.1",
        "webonyx/graphql-php": "^0.13.8",
        "wikimedia/less.php": "^3.0.0",
        "web-token/jwt-framework": "^v2.2.7"
    },
    "suggest": {
        "ext-pcntl": "Need for run processes in parallel mode"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "exclude-from-classmap": [
            "**/dev/**",
            "**/update/**",
            "**/Test/**"
        ],
        "files": [
            "app/etc/NonComposerComponentRegistration.php"
        ],
        "psr-0": {
            "": [
                "app/code/",
                "generated/code/"
            ]
        },
        "psr-4": {
            "Magento\\": "app/code/Magento/",
            "Magento\\Framework\\": "lib/internal/Magento/Framework/",
            "Magento\\Setup\\": "setup/src/Magento/Setup/"
        }
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "allure-framework/allure-phpunit": "~1.4",
        "dealerdirect/phpcodesniffer-composer-installer": "^0.7.0",
        "friendsofphp/php-cs-fixer": "~2.18.1",
        "lusitanian/oauth": "~0.8.10",
        "magento/magento-coding-standard": "*",
        "magento/magento2-functional-testing-framework": "^3.0",
        "pdepend/pdepend": "~2.7.1",
        "phpcompatibility/php-compatibility": "^9.3",
        "phpmd/phpmd": "^2.8.0",
        "phpstan/phpstan": "^0.12.77",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^9",
        "sebastian/phpcpd": "^6.0.3",
        "squizlabs/php_codesniffer": "~3.5.4",
        "symfony/finder": "^5.2"
    },
    "conflict": {
        "gene/bluefoot": "*"
    },
    "replace": {
        "magento/module-marketplace": "100.4.2",
        "magento/module-admin-analytics": "100.4.3",
        "magento/module-admin-notification": "100.4.2",
        "magento/module-advanced-pricing-import-export": "100.4.3",
        "magento/module-amqp": "100.4.1",
        "magento/module-amqp-store": "100.4.1",
        "magento/module-analytics": "100.4.3",
        "magento/module-asynchronous-operations": "100.4.3",
        "magento/module-authorization": "100.4.3",
        "magento/module-advanced-search": "100.4.1",
        "magento/module-backend": "102.0.3",
        "magento/module-backup": "100.4.3",
        "magento/module-bundle": "101.0.3",
        "magento/module-bundle-graph-ql": "100.4.3",
        "magento/module-bundle-import-export": "100.4.2",
        "magento/module-cache-invalidate": "100.4.1",
        "magento/module-captcha": "100.4.3",
        "magento/module-cardinal-commerce": "100.4.1",
        "magento/module-catalog": "104.0.3",
        "magento/module-catalog-customer-graph-ql": "100.4.3",
        "magento/module-catalog-analytics": "100.4.1",
        "magento/module-catalog-import-export": "101.1.3",
        "magento/module-catalog-inventory": "100.4.3",
        "magento/module-catalog-inventory-graph-ql": "100.4.0",
        "magento/module-catalog-rule": "101.2.3",
        "magento/module-catalog-rule-graph-ql": "100.4.1",
        "magento/module-catalog-rule-configurable": "100.4.2",
        "magento/module-catalog-search": "102.0.3",
        "magento/module-catalog-url-rewrite": "100.4.3",
        "magento/module-catalog-widget": "100.4.3",
        "magento/module-checkout": "100.4.3",
        "magento/module-checkout-agreements": "100.4.2",
        "magento/module-checkout-agreements-graph-ql": "100.4.0",
        "magento/module-cms": "104.0.3",
        "magento/module-cms-url-rewrite": "100.4.2",
        "magento/module-compare-list-graph-ql": "100.4.0",
        "magento/module-config": "101.2.3",
        "magento/module-configurable-import-export": "100.4.1",
        "magento/module-configurable-product": "100.4.3",
        "magento/module-configurable-product-sales": "100.4.1",
        "magento/module-contact": "100.4.3",
        "magento/module-cookie": "100.4.3",
        "magento/module-cron": "100.4.3",
        "magento/module-currency-symbol": "100.4.2",
        "magento/module-customer": "103.0.3",
        "magento/module-customer-analytics": "100.4.1",
        "magento/module-customer-downloadable-graph-ql": "100.4.0",
        "magento/module-customer-import-export": "100.4.3",
        "magento/module-deploy": "100.4.3",
        "magento/module-developer": "100.4.3",
        "magento/module-dhl": "100.4.2",
        "magento/module-directory": "100.4.3",
        "magento/module-directory-graph-ql": "100.4.1",
        "magento/module-downloadable": "100.4.3",
        "magento/module-downloadable-graph-ql": "100.4.3",
        "magento/module-downloadable-import-export": "100.4.2",
        "magento/module-eav": "102.1.3",
        "magento/module-elasticsearch": "101.0.3",
        "magento/module-elasticsearch-6": "100.4.3",
        "magento/module-elasticsearch-7": "100.4.3",
        "magento/module-email": "101.1.3",
        "magento/module-encryption-key": "100.4.2",
        "magento/module-fedex": "100.4.2",
        "magento/module-gift-message": "100.4.2",
        "magento/module-gift-message-graph-ql": "100.4.1",
        "magento/module-google-adwords": "100.4.1",
        "magento/module-google-analytics": "100.4.0",
        "magento/module-google-optimizer": "100.4.2",
        "magento/module-graph-ql": "100.4.3",
        "magento/module-graph-ql-cache": "100.4.0",
        "magento/module-catalog-graph-ql": "100.4.3",
        "magento/module-catalog-cms-graph-ql": "100.4.0",
        "magento/module-catalog-url-rewrite-graph-ql": "100.4.2",
        "magento/module-configurable-product-graph-ql": "100.4.3",
        "magento/module-customer-graph-ql": "100.4.3",
        "magento/module-eav-graph-ql": "100.4.1",
        "magento/module-swatches-graph-ql": "100.4.2",
        "magento/module-tax-graph-ql": "100.4.0",
        "magento/module-url-rewrite-graph-ql": "100.4.2",
        "magento/module-cms-url-rewrite-graph-ql": "100.4.1",
        "magento/module-weee-graph-ql": "100.4.1",
        "magento/module-cms-graph-ql": "100.4.1",
        "magento/module-grouped-import-export": "100.4.1",
        "magento/module-grouped-product": "100.4.3",
        "magento/module-grouped-catalog-inventory": "100.4.0",
        "magento/module-grouped-product-graph-ql": "100.4.3",
        "magento/module-import-export": "101.0.3",
        "magento/module-indexer": "100.4.3",
        "magento/module-instant-purchase": "100.4.2",
        "magento/module-integration": "100.4.3",
        "magento/module-layered-navigation": "100.4.3",
        "magento/module-login-as-customer": "100.4.3",
        "magento/module-login-as-customer-admin-ui": "100.4.3",
        "magento/module-login-as-customer-api": "100.4.2",
        "magento/module-login-as-customer-assistance": "100.4.2",
        "magento/module-login-as-customer-frontend-ui": "100.4.3",
        "magento/module-login-as-customer-graph-ql": "100.4.0",
        "magento/module-login-as-customer-log": "100.4.2",
        "magento/module-login-as-customer-quote": "100.4.2",
        "magento/module-login-as-customer-page-cache": "100.4.3",
        "magento/module-login-as-customer-sales": "100.4.3",
        "magento/module-media-content": "100.4.2",
        "magento/module-media-content-api": "100.4.2",
        "magento/module-media-content-catalog": "100.4.2",
        "magento/module-media-content-cms": "100.4.2",
        "magento/module-media-gallery": "100.4.2",
        "magento/module-media-gallery-api": "101.0.2",
        "magento/module-media-gallery-ui": "100.4.2",
        "magento/module-media-gallery-ui-api": "100.4.1",
        "magento/module-media-gallery-integration": "100.4.2",
        "magento/module-media-gallery-synchronization": "100.4.2",
        "magento/module-media-gallery-synchronization-api": "100.4.1",
        "magento/module-media-content-synchronization": "100.4.2",
        "magento/module-media-content-synchronization-api": "100.4.1",
        "magento/module-media-content-synchronization-catalog": "100.4.1",
        "magento/module-media-content-synchronization-cms": "100.4.1",
        "magento/module-media-gallery-synchronization-metadata": "100.4.0",
        "magento/module-media-gallery-metadata": "100.4.1",
        "magento/module-media-gallery-metadata-api": "100.4.0",
        "magento/module-media-gallery-catalog-ui": "100.4.1",
        "magento/module-media-gallery-cms-ui": "100.4.1",
        "magento/module-media-gallery-catalog-integration": "100.4.1",
        "magento/module-media-gallery-catalog": "100.4.1",
        "magento/module-media-gallery-renditions": "100.4.1",
        "magento/module-media-gallery-renditions-api": "100.4.0",
        "magento/module-media-storage": "100.4.2",
        "magento/module-message-queue": "100.4.3",
        "magento/module-msrp": "100.4.2",
        "magento/module-msrp-configurable-product": "100.4.1",
        "magento/module-msrp-grouped-product": "100.4.1",
        "magento/module-multishipping": "100.4.3",
        "magento/module-mysql-mq": "100.4.1",
        "magento/module-new-relic-reporting": "100.4.1",
        "magento/module-newsletter": "100.4.3",
        "magento/module-newsletter-graph-ql": "100.4.0",
        "magento/module-offline-payments": "100.4.2",
        "magento/module-offline-shipping": "100.4.2",
        "magento/module-page-cache": "100.4.3",
        "magento/module-payment": "100.4.3",
        "magento/module-paypal": "101.0.3",
        "magento/module-paypal-captcha": "100.4.1",
        "magento/module-paypal-graph-ql": "100.4.1",
        "magento/module-persistent": "100.4.3",
        "magento/module-product-alert": "100.4.2",
        "magento/module-product-video": "100.4.3",
        "magento/module-quote": "101.2.3",
        "magento/module-quote-analytics": "100.4.3",
        "magento/module-quote-bundle-options": "100.4.0",
        "magento/module-quote-configurable-options": "100.4.0",
        "magento/module-quote-downloadable-links": "100.4.0",
        "magento/module-quote-graph-ql": "100.4.3",
        "magento/module-related-product-graph-ql": "100.4.1",
        "magento/module-release-notification": "100.4.1",
        "magento/module-reports": "100.4.3",
        "magento/module-require-js": "100.4.0",
        "magento/module-review": "100.4.3",
        "magento/module-review-graph-ql": "100.4.0",
        "magento/module-review-analytics": "100.4.1",
        "magento/module-robots": "101.1.0",
        "magento/module-rss": "100.4.2",
        "magento/module-rule": "100.4.2",
        "magento/module-sales": "103.0.3",
        "magento/module-sales-analytics": "100.4.1",
        "magento/module-sales-graph-ql": "100.4.3",
        "magento/module-sales-inventory": "100.4.0",
        "magento/module-sales-rule": "101.2.3",
        "magento/module-sales-sequence": "100.4.1",
        "magento/module-sample-data": "100.4.1",
        "magento/module-search": "101.1.3",
        "magento/module-security": "100.4.3",
        "magento/module-send-friend": "100.4.2",
        "magento/module-send-friend-graph-ql": "100.4.0",
        "magento/module-shipping": "100.4.3",
        "magento/module-sitemap": "100.4.2",
        "magento/module-store": "101.1.3",
        "magento/module-store-graph-ql": "100.4.2",
        "magento/module-swagger": "100.4.2",
        "magento/module-swagger-webapi": "100.4.0",
        "magento/module-swagger-webapi-async": "100.4.0",
        "magento/module-swatches": "100.4.3",
        "magento/module-swatches-layered-navigation": "100.4.0",
        "magento/module-tax": "100.4.3",
        "magento/module-tax-import-export": "100.4.3",
        "magento/module-theme": "101.1.3",
        "magento/module-theme-graph-ql": "100.4.1",
        "magento/module-translation": "100.4.3",
        "magento/module-ui": "101.2.3",
        "magento/module-ups": "100.4.3",
        "magento/module-url-rewrite": "102.0.2",
        "magento/module-user": "101.2.3",
        "magento/module-usps": "100.4.2",
        "magento/module-variable": "100.4.1",
        "magento/module-vault": "101.2.3",
        "magento/module-vault-graph-ql": "100.4.0",
        "magento/module-version": "100.4.0",
        "magento/module-webapi": "100.4.2",
        "magento/module-webapi-async": "100.4.1",
        "magento/module-webapi-security": "100.4.1",
        "magento/module-weee": "100.4.3",
        "magento/module-widget": "101.2.3",
        "magento/module-wishlist": "101.2.3",
        "magento/module-wishlist-graph-ql": "100.4.3",
        "magento/module-wishlist-analytics": "100.4.2",
        "magento/theme-adminhtml-backend": "100.4.3",
        "magento/theme-frontend-blank": "100.4.3",
        "magento/theme-frontend-luma": "100.4.3",
        "magento/language-de_de": "100.4.0",
        "magento/language-en_us": "100.4.0",
        "magento/language-es_es": "100.4.0",
        "magento/language-fr_fr": "100.4.0",
        "magento/language-nl_nl": "100.4.0",
        "magento/language-pt_br": "100.4.0",
        "magento/language-zh_hans_cn": "100.4.0",
        "magento/framework": "103.0.3",
        "magento/framework-amqp": "100.4.1",
        "magento/framework-bulk": "101.0.0",
        "magento/framework-message-queue": "100.4.3",
        "trentrichardson/jquery-timepicker-addon": "1.4.3",
        "components/jquery": "1.11.0",
        "blueimp/jquery-file-upload": "5.6.14",
        "components/jqueryui": "1.10.4",
        "twbs/bootstrap": "3.1.0",
        "tinymce/tinymce": "3.4.7",
        "magento/module-csp": "100.4.2",
        "magento/module-aws-s3": "100.4.1",
        "magento/module-remote-storage": "100.4.1",
        "magento/module-jwt-framework-adapter": "100.4.0"
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Magento\\PhpStan\\": "dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/PhpStan/",
            "Magento\\Sniffs\\": "dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/Sniffs/",
            "Magento\\TestFramework\\Inspection\\": "dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/TestFramework/Inspection/",
            "Magento\\TestFramework\\Utility\\": "dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/TestFramework/Utility/",
            "Magento\\Tools\\": "dev/tools/Magento/Tools/",
            "Magento\\Tools\\Sanity\\": "dev/build/publication/sanity/Magento/Tools/Sanity/"
        }
    },
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "extra": {
        "component_paths": {
            "blueimp/jquery-file-upload": "lib/web/jquery/fileUploader",
            "components/jquery": [
                "lib/web/jquery.js",
                "lib/web/jquery/jquery.min.js",
                "lib/web/jquery/jquery-migrate.js"
            ],
            "components/jqueryui": [
                "lib/web/jquery/jquery-ui.js"
            ],
            "tinymce/tinymce": "lib/web/tiny_mce_4",
            "trentrichardson/jquery-timepicker-addon": "lib/web/jquery/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js",
            "twbs/bootstrap": [
                "lib/web/jquery/jquery.tabs.js"
            ]
        }
    }
}
`
```

Answer (score 1):

**NOW I GET THIS and no getting to get it installed**

[b@66-55-92-54 public_html]$ composer install
PHP Warning:  Module 'sodium' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
Installing dependencies from lock file (including require-dev)
Verifying lock file contents can be installed on current platform.
Warning: The lock file is not up to date with the latest changes in composer.json. You may be getting outdated dependencies. It is recommended that you run `composer update` or `composer update <package name>`.
In Laminas\DependencyPlugin\DependencyRewriterV2::onPrePoolCreate
Nothing to install, update or remove
Package container-interop/container-interop is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use psr/container instead.
Package phpunit/php-token-stream is abandoned, you should avoid using it. No replacement was suggested.
Generating autoload files
109 packages you are using are looking for funding.
Use the `composer fund` command to find out more!
[b@66-55-92-54 public_html]$ composer update
PHP Warning:  Module 'sodium' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
Loading composer repositories with package information
Info from https://repo.packagist.org: #StandWithUkraine
In Laminas\DependencyPlugin\DependencyRewriterV2::onPrePoolCreate
Updating dependencies
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1
- Root composer.json requires magento/inventory-composer-metapackage, it could not be found in any version, there may be atypo in the package name.

Potential causes:

- A typo in the package name
- The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting
  see https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#minimum-stability for more details.
- It's a private package and you forgot to add a custom repository to find it

Read https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md for further common problems.

Answer (score 0):

You can made changes in the composer.json and add the inventory tag in **"require"**

```
"require": {
        "magento/composer-dependency-version-audit-plugin": "~0.1",
        "magento/composer-root-update-plugin": "~2.0",
        "magento/module-bundle-sample-data": "100.4.*",
        "magento/inventory-composer-metapackage": "1.1.*"
}
```

After addding this to composer.json, you need to run

> composer install

Comment: well, it didn't work for me that way but it worked this way.

Comment: well, it didn't work for me that way but it worked this way. i downloaded and uploaded this file,https://github.com/magento/inventory/releases in app/code/magento and run php bin/magento setup:upgrade please check what version works for your magento here https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/commerce-admin/inventory/release-notes.html

Comment: ok, i see...
but i just installed that MSI modules through composer in 2.4.4 in vanilla version. But i guess we can use both ways.

Comment: Root composer.json requires magento/inventory-composer-metapackage, it could not be found in any version,

Answer (score 0):

Inventory packages are included in Magento code base.

As you said, you are downloading the Magento source code directly from Github, you should use Composer to install Magento instead of downloading source code from Github.

Assume you want to install Magento 2.4.3 using Composer, go to your root directory, and run the below command:

```
composer create-project --repository-url=https://repo.magento.com/ magento/project-community-edition=2.4.3 .
```

When it has been done, run the install command like normal:

```
bin/magento setup:install \
--base-url=http://magento2site.com \
--db-host=localhost \
--db-name=magento \
--db-user=magento \
--db-password=magento \
--admin-firstname=admin \
--admin-lastname=admin \
--admin-email=admin@admin.com \
--admin-user=admin \
--admin-password=admin123 \
--language=en_US \
--currency=USD \
--timezone=America/Chicago \
--use-rewrites=1 \
--search-engine=elasticsearch7 \
--elasticsearch-host=es-host.example.com \
--elasticsearch-port=9200 \
--elasticsearch-index-prefix=magento2 \
--elasticsearch-timeout=15
```

Reference: https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/commerce-operations/installation-guide/composer.html

Comment: Can you please help me to solve this issue : https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/362401/magento-2-how-to-protect-magento-search-terms

Comment: @Msquare Sure thing.