# Magento 2 How to validate magento search terms

Tags: magento2, catalogsearch, search-terms

Magento 2 search terms are many invalid entries, special characters, random numbers, Chinese characters string, emoji characters, etc. In search terms, these different types of strings are stored. and when I search on the frontend so this invalid string is showing me in suggestion.

How to protect my search terms? How to validate the search string?

Can anyone help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Below are solutions for removing unwanted search terms in search results.**

**app/code/VendoreName/ModuleName/etc**

**di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Search\Model\ResourceModel\Query\Collection" type="VendoreName\ModuleName\Model\ResourceModel\Query\CollectionUpdate" />
</config>
```

**app/code/VendoreName/ModuleName/Model/ResourceModel/Query**

**CollectionUpdate.php**

```
<?php

namespace VendoreName\ModuleName\Model\ResourceModel\Query;

use Magento\Framework\DB\Select;

class CollectionUpdate extends \Magento\Search\Model\ResourceModel\Query\Collection
{
    /**
     * Set search query text to filter
     *
     * @param string $query
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setQueryFilter($query)
    {
        $notAllowedWords = ['\%','냐ㅣㅑㅅ']; // You can add what you want to remove. If search term contains one of this then it' remove from search result
        $notAllowedString = '';
        if (count($notAllowedWords)) {
            foreach ($notAllowedWords as $notAllowedVal) {
                $notAllowedString .= " AND query_text NOT LIKE '%".$notAllowedVal."%' ";
            }
        }
        $this->getSelect()
            ->reset(Select::FROM)
            ->distinct(true)
            ->from(['main_table' => $this->getTable('search_query')])
            ->reset(Select::COLUMNS)
            ->columns(['query_text', 'num_results', 'popularity'])
            ->where(
                "num_results > 0 AND display_in_terms = 1 AND query_text LIKE ? ".$notAllowedString,
                $this->_resourceHelper->addLikeEscape($query, ['position' => 'start'])
            )
            ->order('popularity ' . \Magento\Framework\DB\Select::SQL_DESC);

        if ($this->getStoreId()) {
            $this->getSelect()->where('store_id = ?', (int)$this->getStoreId());
        }

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Magento already supports protecting search terms by default, so you don't need to validate the search term.

Sometimes you can see strange entries, special characters, etc... on the search result page. There are 3 solutions to remove/exclude these search term records:
**1.** **Remove** them from `search_query` table in the database.
**2.** **Remove** them from the admin panel:
To remove these strange search terms from your search result page, take the following steps:

Step 1. On the Admin sidebar, go to Marketing > SEO & Search > Search Terms.

Step 2. In the Search Terms grid, filtering by Search Query (for example filtering with select text) to get unexpected search terms records.

Step 3. Select unexpected search term records and choose the Delete action.

Step 4. Clear the `config` cache type.

**3.** **Exclude** them from the search result by implementing customized code.
`Magento\AdvancedSearch\Model\ResourceModel\Recommendations::loadByQuery` is responsible for filtering the related search terms for the **Related Search Terms** (Suggestion) section.
You can override this method (loadByQuery) to customize the select query. Replace the following code

```
$select = $connection->select()->from(
    $this->_searchQueryModel->getResource()->getMainTable(),
    ['query_id']
)->where(
    new Zend_Db_Expr($likeCondition)
)->where(
    'store_id=?',
    $this->_searchQueryModel->getStoreId()
)->order(
    'num_results DESC'
)->limit(
    $searchRecommendationsCount + 1
);
```

with

```
$notAllowedWords = ['your not allowed words', 'another word'];
foreach ($notAllowedWords as $word) {
    $notLikeCondition[] = $connection->quoteInto('query_text NOT LIKE ?', $word . '%');
}
$mergedCondition = '(' . $likeCondition . ')' . ' AND ' . implode(' AND ', $notLikeCondition);

$select = $connection->select()->from(
    $this->_searchQueryModel->getResource()->getMainTable(),
    ['query_id']
)->where(
    new Zend_Db_Expr($mergedCondition)
)->where(
    'store_id=?',
    $this->_searchQueryModel->getStoreId()
)->order(
    'num_results DESC'
)->limit(
    $searchRecommendationsCount + 1
);
```

That would be great if you added a new store config in the system configuration that saves the list of not allowed words. It definitely helps the admin user easy to manage these words.

Comment: Thanks for you help me. I checked your answer. For me Magento\AdvancedSearch\Model\ResourceModel\Recommendations::loadByQuery it's not working. Then I found one class Magento\Search\Model\ResourceModel\Query\Collection::setQueryFilter() function which is responsible for show search terms values in frontend. I have overwritten it and update the SQL logic. now it's working.

Comment: Glad to see you sorted it. The search result page has 2 sections: "Did you mean" and "Related search term". I'm talking about "Related search term (Recommendation)", but if you want to modify "Did you mean" section, you should work with `Magento\Elasticsearch\Model\DataProvider\Base\Suggestions::getItems`

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, my above solution is working, And also I install Bot Blocker Module to fix invalid search term keywords.